# springsecurity the /login page <http pattern="/login"> can't work but in <intercept-url> it works well

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security

Forgive my poor English，thanks
this is my spring-security.xml
in this way ,it can't work

```
<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" />
***<http pattern="/login" security="none"/>***
<http pattern="/about" security="none"/>
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
<form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/" password-parameter="pwd"/>
<logout logout-success-url="/about" />
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
 <intercept-url pattern="/user/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
<intercept-url pattern="/admin/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
<custom-filter ref="ipFilter" before="FILTER_SECURITY_INTERCEPTOR" />
<remember-me remember-me-parameter="remember-me" token-validity-seconds="604800" data-source-ref="dataSource" user-service-ref="customjdbcUserService" />
</http>
```

**if the /login url configured like:**

```
***<http pattern="/login" security="none"/>***
```

**,then the login won't work,it just response the login.jsp.
but if the /login was configured in this type**

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
<form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/" password-parameter="pwd" />
<logout logout-success-url="/about" />
***<intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />***
...
</http>
```

**it works well,then I can login my application**

this is the debug-info with the first type(`***<http pattern="/login" security="none"/>***`)

```
21:59:10,651 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:151 - Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/login'
21:59:10,652 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:200 - /login has an empty filter list
21:59:10,652 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:861 - DispatcherServlet with name 'springmvc' processing POST request for [/login]
21:59:10,652 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:294 - Looking up handler method for path /login
21:59:10,652 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:299 - Returning handler method [public void com.bay1ts.controller.BaseController.login()]
21:59:10,652 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:248 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'baseController'
21:59:10,653 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:1241 - Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'login'; URL [/WEB-INF/jsps/login.jsp]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'springmvc'
21:59:10,653 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:248 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'requestDataValueProcessor'
21:59:10,653 DEBUG JstlView:166 - Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/jsps/login.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'login'
21:59:10,661 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:996 - Successfully completed request
```

this is the main part of my login.jsp file

```
<form action="login" method=post>
      <div class="input-container">
        <input type="text" id="Username" name="username" required="required"/>
        <label for="用户名">Username</label>
        <div class="bar"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="input-container">
        <input type="password" id="Password" name="pwd" required="required"/>
        <label for="密码">Password</label>
        <div class="bar"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="Remember-me" name="remember-me" required="required"/>
        <label for="Remember-me">Remember-me</label>
        <div class="checkbox"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="button-container">
        <button><span>Go</span></button>
      </div>
      <div class="footer"><a href="#">忘记密码?</a></div>
      <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
    </form>
```

and this is the baseController

```
@Controller
public class BaseController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index(){
        return "index";
    }
    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public void login(){

    }
    @RequestMapping("/about")
    public String about(){
        return "about";
    }

}
```

my spring security version is 4.0.2

thanks

Comment: thank you Luthando Loot,this is my first question in stackoverflow.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. If I understand you question, I think you need to change the form action URL as follows 
<form method="post" action="<c:url value='/j_spring_security_check'/>"  >

Comment: but why the login  works well when I didn't use the "<c:url value='/j_spring_security_check'/> in the form,just only place the pattern /login like this:<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
  <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />

Comment: You write it works well, so what is your question?

Comment: in this format <http pattern="/login" security="none"/>,it can't work

Comment: but in this way <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitALL" />,it works well